# Questions on Angular Upgrade checklist

Tags: angular

The steps of the [upgrade checklist](https://update.angular.io/?v=14.0-16.0) are a bit vague, could use some direction.

For the first outlined item, does this mean to update the class in the index.d.ts file?  If this is what is supposed to be done, wouldn't this get overwritten on the next Angular upgrade?  Where a title does not exist in a class, then its instances should be extended makes more sense in this case. If this is true, how would this be done?  Of course, adding the property in the class in the index.d.ts file, then using it in each instance (or setting the string empty, etc.) would be easiest.

For the 2nd item, providedIn: 'root' is how all instances of this attribute are used.  I'm taking it for granted the upgrade step is to be interpreted exactly -- providedIn: 'any' is deprecated but providedIn: 'root' would not be.

The read more links here don't tell a lot more, just how and when the checklist items were created and in which pull requests.

Thanks in advance for anyone's help.

[image: See Outlined Checklist Items]

Comment: Please include text as text, not as a picture of text. Search engines don't index text in images, so people with the same question(s) won't find this one. See [the Meta Stack Overflow FAQ about this issue for more.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Yeah no idea what 1st means as stated. I assume it's referring to the fact you can put title property on your routes (and so this is passed to the snapshot) so if you're relying on the type to check this? 2nd item - yes, as always can also leave this off if providing at a component level `@Injectable() export SomeService {}`

Comment: Andrew, thanks again for the answer.  What puzzles me is no title exists on any instance of ActivatedRouteSnapshot in the solution but it works.  If Title is a required property, then how does the the ActivatedRouteSnapshot class not have this property after the upgrade?  One would think the title would be there now, if it's required, once the hop to 15 is successful.  Am somewhat new to Angular, what am I missing here?

Comment: Andrew, comments only allow so much text.  I did try adding title: to the index.d.ts ActivatedRouteSnapshot class.  As get title() already exists as a method, title can't be added to the class.  sure enough, when the compile was attempted in the DOS CMD window it blew up.  Your clarification that the title *may* be added to the route appears correct, thus.